# hacer un append de valores con PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de copiar los valores que son generados a partir de un formulario de PyQt5 y quiero almacenarlos en una lista para poder acceder globalmente.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agrega un valor númerico. Se escoge un valor del spinbox y se muestra en el label, se totaliza y ese es el valor que deseo que se agregue a una lista.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PuntoVentaDialog import PuntoVentaDialog

    # clase personalizada que hereda de Qdialog

class PuntoVentaApplication(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = PuntoVentaDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.sb_Mouse.valueChanged.connect(self.calcular_total)


    def calcular_total(self):
        # primero capturar precio del mouse
        precio_mouse = int(self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_valor.text())
        # capturar cantidad de mouse
        cantidad_mouse = int(self.ui.sb_Mouse.value())
        # operar variables
        subtotal_mouse = precio_mouse * cantidad_mouse
        # set el valor de variable subtotal a line edit subtotal
        self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_subtotal.setText(str(subtotal_mouse))
        # asignar variable subtotal a total

        total = subtotal_mouse
        # asignar valor total para display en el label
        self.ui.lb_total.setText(str(total))
        return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes crear una lista en el constructor y ir añadiendo, algo así!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PuntoVentaDialog import PuntoVentaDialog

    # clase personalizada que hereda de Qdialog

class PuntoVentaApplication(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = PuntoVentaDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.sb_Mouse.valueChanged.connect(self.calcular_total)
        self.lista_valores = []

    def calcular_total(self):
        # primero capturar precio del mouse
        precio_mouse = int(self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_valor.text())
        # capturar cantidad de mouse
        cantidad_mouse = int(self.ui.sb_Mouse.value())
        # operar variables
        subtotal_mouse = precio_mouse * cantidad_mouse
        # set el valor de variable subtotal a line edit subtotal
        self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_subtotal.setText(str(subtotal_mouse))
        # asignar variable subtotal a total
        total = subtotal_mouse
        # agregar a la lista de valores el valor total
        self.lista_valores.append(total)
        # asignar valor total para display en el label
        self.ui.lb_total.setText(str(total))
        return total
```

Comment: muchas gracias, creo que funciona, solo que para comprobar si el ultimo valor es guardado, como puedo decirle que me imprima en la terminal, utilize print(self.lista_valores) dentro de la funcion calcular_total pero me aparece name 'self' is not defined, como puedo hacer esta comprobacion cuando la ventana principal es ejecutada?, gracias

Comment: @JhonMoreno esta bien lo que haces, solo asegúrate de que esta al final antes del return

Comment: perfecto, Eureka : )